# How to pass WHERE condition as PDO prepared statement parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, where-clause

I'm trying to make a simple project using PDO. I have a class **UserDAO** with two SELECT functions:

```
public function getAll(){
 $query="select * from users";
 $res = $this->db->query($query);
 return $res;
}
```

...and this one...

```
public function getAllWhere($where){
 $query="select * from users where ?";
 $res = $this->db->query($query,array($where));
 return $res; 
}
```

When I call the function **getAll()**, it works fine:

```
<?php
 $ud = new UserDAO();
 $result=$ud->getAll();
 foreach ($result as $row){
   echo '<br/>'.$row['id'].' '.$row['username'];
}
?>
```

But when I try to user the other function...

```
<?php
 $ud = new UserDAO();
 $result=$ud->getAllWhere('id>10');
 foreach ($result as $row){
   echo '<br/>'.$row['id'].' '.$row['username'];
}
?>
```

...it doesn't work. The error is:

**PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given**

How can I pass the whole WHERE condition as a parameter? I would also like to make another step forward and to insert the table name ("users") as a parameter too.

Thanks.

Comment: `where ?` you can't bind a column.

Comment: placeholders can only represent **VALUES**. They cannot represent sql keywords/fieldnames/tablenames. What you want is not possible.